# Make a statement to ensure that you get the coin?

Tags: logical-deduction

This story takes us back to the times of *King Vikramaditya*. The king was possessed by a demon called *Betal* who once asked him a tricky question to judge his wit. He showed him three coins (gold, silver and copper) and told him that if he made a true statement, he'll get a coin else he won't be getting any of the coins. Imagine yourself to be Vikramaditya and try and make an apt statement which would ensure that you get a gold coin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"You'll either give me the gold coin or no coin."

If the demon gives the gold coin, the statement was true and I received a coin, so everything is OK.

If the demon gives me a silver or copper coin, the statement was false and I received a coin, so it can't happen.

If the demon gives me no coin, the statement was true and I received no coin, so it can't happen.

As you see by asking "You'll either give me the gold coin or no coin." the only possible outcome would be receiving the gold coin.

EDIT for clarification:

Let's imagine the two scenarios, where the sentence I said is true and where it's false.

> First Scenario ("You'll either give me the gold coin or no coin." is true):
>
> Since it's true, the demon will give me a coin; but if it's true and the demon gives me a coin, it must be the gold coin (since it was true that he would give me the gold coin).
>
> Second Scenario ("You'll either give me the gold coin or no coin." is false):
>
> Since it's false, he will give me no coin. But we just assumed that the statement "You'll give me no coin" (a variant of it actually) is false.
>
> Therefore, Second Scenario can't happen.

Comment: Why the last two can't happen? And I didn't understand the copper and silver part.

Comment: I think your answer is correct but explanation is wrong. Because if he was giving me gold, then yes, it would be right. If he was giving me no coin, then also it would be right. But if he was giving him any of the two other ones, then the statement would turn out to be false and he would receive no coin. But finally his statement would be true. So if we add **"finally"** to your answer. So in that case it would be right.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal The answer assumes that the demon is bound by the rules as given.  So there is no finally involved, the demon would break the rules if he gives a silver coin and no gold coin.

Comment: You could also say "You will not give me a copper coin or a silver coin."  Logically, it is exactly the same, but some might find the explanation easier.

Comment: So what would the demon do if you said "You will give me no coins." ?

Comment: I would suggest "*Today*, you'll either give me the gold coin or no coin."  An evil demon might otherwise delay an arbitrarily long time before handing over the coin.

Comment: How about "If you give me any coins, you will give me the gold coin along with a chest full of rubies and a lifetime supply of Wonka bars."

Comment: @supercat at first glance that statement is false and he receives no coins. Nothing has been promised about Wonka bars and thus our demon is able to refute the claim that he would be giving any regardless of the truth of the rest of our protagonists statement.

Comment: @JacobRaihle: The statement "If X then Y" will be vacuously true when X is false, regardless of the truth or falsehood of Y.  An clearer alternative with the same meaning would be "You will not give me the coin without also giving me [other goodies]".

Answer (score 3):

Why stop at one coin? Get all three!

Just say:

> The number of coins you give me can be divided by 3 without remainder!

This is exactly true when he gives you 0 or 3 coins. As a true statement together with 0 coins is not possible, the demon Betal has to give you all three coins, including the gold coin!

Comment: Your answer assumes the fact that more than one coin can be given. You could take the statement `he made a true statement, he'll get a coin else he won't ` literally and say that you only get one coin.

Comment: @tfitzger if you take the statement literally it just means 'he gets a coin', not 'he gets only one coin'. And the statement 'he gets a coin' is true, regardless if he also gets another coin after that or if the Daemon also gives him a castle, it stays true as long as he did in fact get (at least) a coin.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use force?

> "Either you will give me the gold coin OR I will commit suicide."

Explanation:

> Since the demon is possessing you, it must comply, or perish alongside you.